# Issue with Difference In Proxies

Tags: proxy, ip, squid, cloud

I have been recently diving deep into making proxies using servers and such. There are multiple proxy companies where their proxy IPs are traced back to https://www.hetzner.com/. These proxies provide top of the line **UNITED STATES** proxies yet hetzner is a service in Denmark. The proxies made by the companies work perfectly on United States websites and has no issues when it comes to proxy bans. I'd assume that the proxy companies are obviously using the hetzner servers as proxy servers and making proxies using those servers. The problem is that I wanted to recreate that, and I bought myself a server at https://www.hetzner.com/ and setup a proxy server using 3proxy. However, the proxy I made is banned by many United States websites because it is a proxy from **DENMARK** and I can't really do anything with it. What makes my proxy so different? Should I be using squid instead of 3proxy? Is there a specific line of code I should add? Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: The server I bought from hetzner is a cloud server

Comment: Hetzner data centers are in Germany and Finland as far as I know, so your question makes no sense in that regard. Additionally proxy providers will typically have some form of backend network which routes your traffic from their proxy server (which can be near to you  and/or at Hetzner) to an egress point with a different  IP address address and a different geo-IP location  (of your choice)

Comment: Something is wrong with either your IP address lookup service, the IP addresses you looked up, or both. Hetzner cloud servers are in Germany and Finland, not Denmark or the USA. But you didn't provide any relevant details (such as the actual IP addresses) so it is not possible to verify anything.